# Magento2 product url displaying with category and product id

Tags: magento2, product-urls, catalog-url-rewrite

Product urls are displaying with category and product id

Now url is displaying like below http://localhost/magento2/catalog/product/view/id/1234/category/12/

But i want http://localhost/magento2/test-product

Comment: You should reindex and check again.

Comment: I did reindex and cleared cache, only few products have this issue

Comment: How you created these products?

Comment: From magento admin

Comment: Please save the category again. The issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to edit 1st level or 2nd level categories and simply save it and it will generates rewrites for products assigned to that category. This worked for me when i migrated store from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

We can configure it by **URL Rewrites**

1. Go to Magento 2 Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites
2. Find the path by searching `Request path` column.
3. Remove the cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`.
4. Refresh the front-end, click the main menu category then you can see the configured path.

**Or**

You Can Build category URL path by

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php
```

Modify `getUrlPath($category)` by Magento Plug-in feature.

Hope this helps.